# Position of div blocks (simple css issue)

Tags: html, css, position

I have an issue in my project:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

I do in css for desctop @media (min-width:768px) options display block and float left. For first with 70% for second 30%.
In mobile I need 100% width both of them and need to display div2 on top div1. Float right for first and float left for second not working. Need your help guys.

Comment: Can you post your CSS?

Comment: show us what have you tried

Comment: #div1 { float: right; display: block; width: 100%; } #div2 { float: left; display: block; width: 100%; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? Flex box allows you to specify the direction of it and also if you are really picky you can specify order number on the item itself.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#div2 {
   width:30%;
   height:300px;
   background:red;
}

#div1 {
   width:70%;
   height:300px;
   background:green;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #div1, #div2{
    width: 100%;
  }
  #container {
    flex-flow: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1">1</div>
  <div id="div2">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, right, flex would solve this, and i think nowdays most browser will support it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want div2 on top, your html have to move div2 on top of div1

```css
#div2 {
   width:30%;
   height:300px;
   background:red;
   float:right
}

#div1 {
   width:70%;
   height:300px;
   background:yellow;
   float:left
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
#div1, #div2 {
  width:100%;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<div id="div1">div1</div>
```

Comment: Yes, your are right, i changed div2 to float to right, then div1 will be on the left

Comment: yes, but can we make this with leaving div1 block at first in HTML code? Why div1 and div2 floats not working?

Comment: If leave div1 first, desktop version will always work, but if your windows size below 768px, when it renders, it reads the first div1 block and becasue its width is now 100%, so it will display first, but we want the div2 to be on top of div1, so we have to put div2 first